# Is that possible to execute a function just after reload...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a set of code

```
setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.reload(true);
   if ($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id) {
       angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.attribute.parentAttribute.id)).click();
   }
}, 1000);
```

I am using a timeout, I need to execute that click function after `window.location.reload(true);` reload cause by this line. Is it possible?

Comment: nope , you are reloading the page  before you trigger click

Comment: Yes, set a flag in local storage, then reload, then test that flag from an onload or DOM ready handler and trigger the click from there.

Comment: You would need to do it on the load event.

Comment: any one can demonstrate please?

Answer (score 1):

Define your handler for the onload event here. This will trigger after a page load (reload is no different):

```
object.onload=function(){myScript}; //in this case object = window
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `onload` method from your starting body tag:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you have called `window.location.reload(true);` then
1. your page will refresh/reload.
2. all the javascript will reload on the page.
3. all the triggers or callbacks will be destroyed/cancelled.

So in short there is no way to call a function after a reload call is made.

All you can do is call a function at page load time as shown below.

```
$(function(){
  // this will be executed first when page loads.
});
```

But there is one glitch with this, this will execute the function whenever the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$window.onload = function() {
  /*do your thing*/
};
```

You will need to inject $window into your controller or run, etc