# Calling a function after location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

At a certain point I call `location.reload()` and I want to call a method after that page reloads.

I do not mind if doing this the method is called every time I visit this page.

Thanks.

----------------------------EDIT----------------------------

I tried this but doesn't work on my javascript

```
$(function(){
 //stuff
});
```

Comment: *is it possible to do that?* **Yes**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is that possible to execute a function just after reload...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473589/is-that-possible-to-execute-a-function-just-after-reload)

Answer (score 3):

> I do not mind if doing this the method is called every time I visit this page.

Then just put it in a part of your script that runs unconditionally, e.g.:

```
runThis();
```

...outside of any conditional blocks. It will be run every time the page loads.

Comment: I read this before, and I tried something, edited question to show it @T.J Crowder

Comment: @PabloCasas: What you've shown in the edit will definitely run ***if*** A) You have jQuery correctly loaded on the page, B) That code is *after* the `script` element including jQuery.

Comment: Will check it again, but doesn't executed previously, thanks